# Marrying Mr. Darcy - Can Kitty Bennet play one more turn after the last turn?

Tags: marrying-mr-darcy

In the card game "Marrying Mr. Darcy", Kitty Bennet's special power states that

> When it's time to draw an Event Crad, she can choose to draw the top discarded Event Card instead.

Usually, when the last Event Card is drawn, the game ends. However, if the last Event Card is drawn by the player to the right of Kitty Bennet, can Kitty still take one more turn by re-drawing that same last Event Card after it is discarded? or is the game immediately over when the last Event Card is intially drawn regardless of Kitty's special power?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, she can't take one more turn by re-drawing that last event card. The game enters the Proposal Stage as soon as that last card was played.

From the [rules](http://www.marryingmrdarcy.com/uploads/7/0/3/4/7034222/instructions-forweb2.pdf):

> When all Event Cards have been played, the Proposal Stage
> begins immediately